# Hi! I would like to connect my LED lights (Vaxmyra from IKEA) designed for 24V system into my 12V system, do I need a current limiting resistor?

Tags: led, current, resistors, current-limiting

I bought these VAXMYRA LEDs thinking they were made for 12V but apparently they need to be feeded 24V.
Supposedly I'll have to install a 24V DC step-up converter, but this device can deliver up to 3A current. I opened the Vaxmyra LED fixture and I could see there are 8 resistors built in (or at least I think they are resistors), but does this mean that I don't need a current limiting resistor befor each vaxmyra light I plan to install in my circuit? [image]

Comment: I strongly advise you to get the proper adapter from Ikea to power these LED lamps. Of course something can be constructed to make these 24 V lamps use that 12 V you already have. However, that isn't something a beginner can do. Your 12 V might be AC and this LED lamp needs DC. You either need to learn **a lot** to be able to construct something that can reliably use your 12 V source to power these lamps. Is that really worth the effort?

Comment: Take them back to Ikea and get the right ones would make sense to me.

Comment: @bimp wiring a simple step up module isn't something a beginner can do? What?

Comment: @Passerby What if the 12 V was AC, the step up would blow up. If you care to explain to OP how to determine if the 12 V is AC or DC and what to do when it is AC, be my guest. Actually AC would be easier as then you can easily make 24 V with some diodes and smoothing caps. With some experience and understanding: easy to do. For a newbee: not so.

Answer (score 1):

The PCB is likely designed in the same way that LED strips are meaning that the series LEDs are expecting a 24V rail like shown below,

[image]

If you deliver 12V to a strip expecting 24V the voltage divided between the series LEDs doesn't add up! You would need to in theory half the length of the series LED paths for 12V to work and that's not going to happen. No single component is going to fix this problem, without a new PCB design or a 24V supply.

Your only option would be to step up the 12V supply you have to 24V but that seems like more of a headache than it's worth.

Comment: Yes this agrees with my observation.

Comment: a boost converter module is a single component solution... like op mentions in the question.

Comment: Poor wording agreed. I was more referring to a passive component like OP referred to. I did suggest stepping up the 12V to 24V in my answer, I would not consider a module as a component personally.

Comment: Ops title is worded poorly as well. But their question shows they know they need a 24V module. Their question is if they needed an extra resistor to limit the boost module's 3A output.

Answer (score 0):

Yes these contain their own Current limiting resistors .

I see 2 SMD’s per 3 strings of 6 x3=18 LEDs.  (6S3P)
6x3.2V=19.2V +IR= 24V where IR is shared power dissipation by 2 SMD’s and tolerant of wide variation of Vf in LED’s

You could :

A) get a large single 24Vdc supply and a motor driver board to act as a Buck dimmer or,

B) get the IKEA 18W supply for each pair (8W each)

C) return them and get dimmable PAR30 Edison AC bulbs and PAR fixtures  with a Triac dimmer.

D) none of the above

These appear to have temp sensing indicators which tells me, the fixture needs to be vented.

At one time I thought the modern house ought to have 24V or 48Vdc shared throughout the home then universal plugs for every peripheral, but it seems USB 5V has become that bus which is only good for short hauls with high currents 12W per port.

Comment: At one time I thought Nicola Tesla's Wardenclyffe tower was the great solution.

Comment: free energy .... or  grid energy black hole?

Comment: "free" can also mean "release"

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The pucks already have current limiting resistors for their led segments. Simply applying 22 to 24 volts will power these pucks just like it would a 24V led strip. A lower voltage would mean slightly dimmer leds but longer life.

Your 3A step up module can provide up to 3A, but the leds will only draw what they need. **Current is pulled not pushed**. And with the resistors on board it will be limited to about 60 mA for the puck. Just make sure your 12V supply can support the load. An average step up regulator is 80 percent efficient, so for a 24V 60mA or 1.4W output you need roughly 1.7W or 12V 140 mA in.